# connecting sql server from dotnet through ODBC Driver

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Let us consider the following connection string which connects sql server through odbc driver as

```
"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=xxx.xx.xx.xx,xxxx;Database=mydata;Uid=xx;Pwd=xxxxxx;"
```

while running this command i am getting error as

```
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Registry information is corrupt or missing. Make sure the provider installed and registered correctly.

ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Client unable to establish connection

ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
2013-02-12 12:17:00,247 

ERROR    
Error at Executenonquery:ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized
```

i too have enabled remote connections in that machine.

in the current machine: visual studio is expired and sql server 2008 r2 in not installed .

What i have to do now in order to solve the issue

Waiting for your responses..

Update:

While i am registering driver in Administrative Data source[odbc] in system i am getting response as

```
Connection failed 

sqlsatte:'08001'

Sql Server Error:27

Registry information is corrupt or missing.
```

Comment: Does the OS eventlog tell you something?

Comment: @ling.s where can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you might have issues with your SQL Native Client installation. Take a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on Installing/Unistalling SQL Server Native Client and where you should be able to find the installed files. It might be worthwhile uninstalling and re-installing it.

Once you've established that it is installed OK, use the ODBC Administrator tool (assuming you are using XP) to set up and test the ODBC connection.

[image: ODBC Admin window showing SQL Native Client 10 installation]